# How to setup Python/Jython in IBM BPM

Tags: jython, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I want to configure Python/Jython in IBM BPM, so that these files can directly executed from process app. How can I do that?
How to setup this entry in WebSphere Application Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to install python or jython on IBM BPM , if you need it to make deploy using WAS command line , there're commands that not related to jython or python and can do the same.

Comment: I need to invoke Python APIs via BPM, can you suggest a way for that?
These APIs are pure Python APIs and not REST APIs.

Comment: I think you can use Soap API to call them remotely through any language programming

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that IBM BPM Standard really handles this use case (although more details would help).  It is possible it maybe part of the "Advanced" offering, but I'm not as familiar with the integration designer product.

IBM BPM Standard allows you to call java code directly either as LiveConnect (bad) or executing java code you place in JAR files in the server files of your Process App (good).  I have seen this used to leverage the Java ability to call command line scripts in order to issue some of the WASAdmin scripts, but that has been the limit of the integration with jython that I have seen.

For details about creating Java connectors you can use  this article - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1206_olivieri/1206_olivieri.html.  While it says 7.5.1 the approach works for TeamWorks 7 through IBM BPM 8.5.5

Can you give more details about the use case you are trying to meet with this technical approach?

Comment: Thanks Drux! I had some python code which I wanted to utilize as is, in the IBM BPM. 
The link you gave is a great help. Could you help further in using jython or finding a way out for using the puthon code?

Comment: I'm not a python guy, so don't have the context to tell you how to execute it.  I believe that python is generally invoked from the command line.  You could then use Java to invoke the desired command line options.  However I'm still interested in the specific use case as this does't feel like the right thing to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any system process api/command using java, java code can be called by using as jar libraries.

System process api/command can execute python or any other code.

```
IBM BPM > Jar libs > System (OS) Process API/Commands > Python
```

I haven't come across any such use case.